# Why the question "Has UK Trade and Investment (UKTI) agreed to certify your maintainance?"

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, dependent-visa

I living and working in the UK under a *Global Talent visa*. My partner is currently applying for a dependant visa and, on the online application form, is asked the following question:

> Has UK Trade and Investment (UKTI) agreed to certify your maintainance?
>
> *If you are unsure ask, [your partner with the Global Talent visa, which is me]. You can check this on their funding endorsement letter.*

We are confused by this question because it is oddly specific and it is unclear to us whether this is a necessary requirement. I am endoresed by UK**R**I (UK Research and Innovation) and have never heard anything of UKTI.

> **Question:** Are we right in answering this question with 'No'?

We are worried that we are missing something crucial and will not have the chance to explain our confusion.

---

As a side question: if the success of the application hinges on our answer to this question, will UK Visa and Immagration contact us about this, or will there just be a rejection with no chance for explaining ourselves?

Comment: Have you asked UKRI about this issue?

Comment: It seems especially weird that they ask that since [UKTI (under that name) ceased to exist in 2016](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-trade-investment).

Comment: How soon into completing the application does this question appear? Try answering ‘yes’ to see what route that leads down, then go back and amend as appropriate

Answer (score 4):

While I have no further information on *why* this was asked, I can at least provide an update on the situation.

Eventually, we decided to submit the visa application with answering *No* on this question. This had no bad effects and the visa was granted with no delays or further queries.

Comment: My guess is that there is a thin sliver of potential applicants where the answer is 'yes', and they would likely specifically know that the question will be asked on the applicants and how to answer it.